# React Vite + Typescript fails in Jenkins but succeeds locally

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jenkins, vite

I have a project with React Vite + Typescript + SWC.
When I try to build it in my machine, and I have also tried in my co-works' machine, it builds successfully, I can test it and everything is working fine, but when I try to buld it in a Jenkins pipeline it fails.

I get the following error:

```bash
17:23:17 rendering chunks...
17:23:37 [31m[vite:build-html] The "fileName" or "name" properties of emitted chunks and assets must be strings that are neither absolute nor relative paths, received "f:/Jenkins/workspace/CI.DevOps/web/index.html".[39m
17:23:37 [32mâœ“ built in 54.67s[39m
17:23:37 [31merror during build:
17:23:37 RollupError: The "fileName" or "name" properties of emitted chunks and assets must be strings that are neither absolute nor relative paths, received "f:/Jenkins/workspace/CI.DevOps/web/index.html".
17:23:37     at error (file:///f:/Jenkins/workspace/CI.DevOps/web/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:337:30)
17:23:37     at FileEmitter.emitFile (file:///f:/Jenkins/workspace/CI.DevOps/web/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18145:24)
17:23:37     at Object.generateBundle (file:///f:/Jenkins/workspace/CI.DevOps/web/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-R0I0XnyH.js:38945:22)
17:23:37     at async Bundle.generate (file:///f:/Jenkins/workspace/CI.DevOps/web/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:17006:9)
17:23:37     at async file:///f:/Jenkins/workspace/CI.DevOps/web/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19552:27
17:23:37     at async catchUnfinishedHookActions (file:///f:/Jenkins/workspace/CI.DevOps/web/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18983:16)
17:23:37     at async build (file:///f:/Jenkins/workspace/CI.DevOps/web/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-R0I0XnyH.js:66815:22)
17:23:37     at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///f:/Jenkins/workspace/CI.DevOps/web/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:845:9)�[39m
17:23:37 error Command failed with exit code 1.
17:23:37 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
17:23:37 Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2023", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es2022",

    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

    "allowJs": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": { "@/*": ["src/*"] }
  },
  "include": ["src", ".eslintrc.js"]
}
```

This is my `vite.config.ts`

```js
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import path from 'path';
import { visualizer } from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer';
import { defineConfig, PluginOption } from 'vite';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    svgr(),
    visualizer({
      template: 'treemap',
      gzipSize: true,
      brotliSize: true,
      filename: '.stats/treemap.html',
    }) as PluginOption,
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
});
```

In my jenkins pipeline I'm simply running "yarn && yarn build".
This is my yarn build command:

```json
"build": "cross-env CI=false && tsc && vite build --outDir build",
```

Comment: Are you running the same versions of yarn / node  and so on?

Comment: both my local environment and this server have the same versions: Node: 20.10.0, Yarn: 1.22.19 and npm: 10.2.3

Answer (score 2):

I have found the issue that was causing the problem. It was related to symbolic links inside the Jenkins server. I had to add the line 'preserveSymlinks: true' to fix it. Here's the updated code:

```js
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import path from 'path';
import { visualizer } from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer';
import { defineConfig, PluginOption } from 'vite';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    svgr(),
    visualizer({
      template: 'treemap',
      gzipSize: true,
      brotliSize: true,
      filename: '.stats/treemap.html',
    }) as PluginOption,
  ],
  resolve: {
    preserveSymlinks: true, // <- this line
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. Here are some other common "works on my machine" sources of error if this happens to you again: environmental variable values, phantom dependencies, cached native lib dependencies for the wrong architecture (e.g. you use libpq and you've cached it locally for your intel box but your CI server is ARM), and the already mentioned version differences in package manager, nodejs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`Found it, I think:

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import path from 'path';
import { visualizer } from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer';
import { defineConfig, PluginOption } from 'vite';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    svgr(),
    visualizer({
      template: 'treemap',
      gzipSize: true,
      brotliSize: true,
      filename: path.resolve(__dirname, '.stats/treemap.html'),
    }) as PluginOption,
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
});
```

The filename here is relative, not aboslute. Maybe you have a file in the .gitignore that is not pushed and ignore that error

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort. I tried using path.resolve(__dirname, '.stats/treemap.html'), but I got the same error. Then I completely removed visualizer and it still threw the same error :/. About .gitignore I don't think it is the case because I have cloned the repository and built it again and it works, but when I run it using the Jenkins pipeline it crashes. If I enter the server and open cmd, run yarn then yarn build, it works, but if I use jenkins service that is installed in this server, it crashes.